# why is GNU make not filling out the $^ variable here?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I can compile the project just fine if I run the project by hand with `g++ source/* -lSDL2 -o bin/fly_fishing`. When I do run make, I get

```
mkdir -p bin
g++   -lSDL2 -o bin/fly_fishing
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:20: bin/fly_fishing] Error 1
```

Which tells me that it's not populating from $^ for linking. So what have I missed here? Here's the makefile for reference.

```
 SRC_DIR := source
OBJ_DIR := objects
BIN_DIR := bin 

EXE := $(BIN_DIR)/fly_fishing
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

CXXFLAGS := -Wall
#CFLAGS   := -Wall
LDLIBS   := -lSDL2a
LDFLAGS :=

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ) | $(BIN_DIR)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR):
        mkdir -p $@

clean:
        @$(RM) -rv $(BIN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)

-include $(OBJ:.o=.d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which tells me that it's not populating from $^ for linking.

That seems unlikely.  Much more likely would be that `$^` expands to nothing.  Which would be the case if `$(OBJ)` expands to nothing.  Which seems plausible because I don't see any corresponding objects being built (though perhaps you've omitted that, or they were built on a previous run).  And `$(OBJ)` expanding to nothing implies that `$(SRC)` expands to nothing.

> So what have I missed here?

That `$(SRC)` expands to nothing is not inconsistent with the data presented.  I observe that the manual compilation command you present is

> ```
> g++ source/* -lSDL2 -o bin/fly_fishing
> ```

That does seem to suggest that there are indeed source files in `source/`, but do they match the pattern `source/*.c`?  Since you're compiling with `g++`, I bet not.  It would be highly unconventional to name C++ source files to end with `.c`, and surely you would not attempt to compile C source files with a C++ compiler.  I infer, then, that your source files are all named with `.cpp`, or maybe `.cc` or `.C`, all of which forms are conventions for C++ source names.

If all your source names follow one or another of those patterns then indeed, this ...

> ```
> SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)
> ```

... will result in `$(SRC)` being empty.

Comment: >"That does seem to suggest that there are indeed source files in source/, but do they match the pattern source/*.c?" 

They ... do not. Now I feel silly not having seen that sooner. Changing the pattern matching to sources/*.cpp now does it all correctly. Thank you for your help. I've marked your post as the answer.

 Edit: pressed enter too soon